# AWS SAM Nodejs runtime with TypeScript template error

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm using AWS SAM with NODEJS16 runtime selecting the ***2 - Hello World Example TypeScript*** template (image for all selected options) [image: AWS SAM selected options].

And then running
`sam local start-api` for local testing.

I'm getting the following error when entering to http://127.0.0.1:3000/hello:

```
ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'app'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs","stack":["Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'app'","Require stack:","- /var/runtime/index.mjs","    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:951:17)","    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:976:21)","    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1137:23)","    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1143:1"]}
```

BUT, if I select the ***1 - Hello World Example*** template, it is working fine, do I need to do something additional to be working with TypeScript template?
I also tried with node14 but still getting the same error for TypeScript template.

Additionally, if I deploy the lambda function (***2 - Hello World Example TypeScript*** template) is working fine in AWS (`sam build/sam deploy --guided`), but I need to run it locally...

I'm not sure if it matters but I'm using MacBook with M1 processor.